# How to get gallery images in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the task to implement something **similar to UIImagePickerController** for displaying and selecting images. The problem is to get the list of images on the device. I can't find any solution to get the images. So is there the way to get images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754496/using-uiimagepicker-in-a-tabbed-uipopover) there is a refence [there](https://github.com/key1jp/ELCImagePickerController).
It is looking interesting.

If not what you seek, you can create your own UIImagePicker, and you will need to go through the [Assets Library framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) to get access to the photos of the iPhone

[The Assets Library framework provides access to the photos and videos in the user’s photo library.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html)

Answer (score 3):

See [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ALAssetsLibrary) class.

An instance of ALAssetsLibrary provides access to the videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

Code might be something like this

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
    }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
    };

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Failure");
                     }];
```